# Displaying Error Page in WP7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7

Just want to check I have not missed anything obvious. There is no way to Navigate the user to a "ooops something bad has happened" page from the UnhandledException handler is there?

What is everyone else doing

I know I can "handle" the error and popup up messagebox but I would prefer a whole page offering them the oppurtunity to file a bug report.

The samples I have seen simply set the RootFrame directly but I have seen that just makes for a messy UI with what looks like a Page displayed on top of another page

TIA

Pat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get an UnhandledException it occurs while your applicaiton is about to be shut down. The best you can do in this situation is warn the user that something went wrong (using a messagebox or similar) but be prepared that this may not be displayed to the user for long, depending on the actual exception.

Rather than try and continue executing application functionality when an unhandled exception occurs, simply save the details of the exception. Then, when the application is next started, display a message to the user to indicate that "the last time that app ran there was a problem". You can also use this opportunity to send exception details to yourself/ your web reporting service so you can analyse the issues and fix/prevent them in a future version.

Comment: I went with Matt's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can call RootFrame.Navigate(*your errorPage*) to navigate to your custom error page in the UnhandledException handler.

Basically, using a custom MessageBox to show a nice easy-going error info and providing an button to send bug report is very common. And [this article is MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278407%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) pointed out that errorinfo not be a separate page in best practice.

Comment: Tried navigating via RootFrame and that gives a similar UX to the one you get when setting Source direct. Depending on where in the page lifecycle you are you can end up with two page visuals. I get the whole "Places" naivgation approach that MSDN best practive gives but a MessageBox is IMHO nasty and a popup box yuk!

Comment: The System's MessageBox is awful, but you can totally made one for yourself, as nice as you want. May be you can check out the [Coding4Fun Toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/)