# Code for unhandled exception not working

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, exception

I am using following code for unhandled exceptions.

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
           System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }


        e.Handled = true;
        Error.Exp = e.ExceptionObject;
        (RootVisual as Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationFrame).Source = new Uri("/Error.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    }
```

This code should direct the control to `Error.xaml` page but it goes to visual studio with the error message of the exception (even after commenting out `if` block). What is wrong here ?

The source of error is

```
GeneralTransform generalTransform1 = canvas1.TransformToVisual(start_rec);
```

Error message was
"Argument exception was unhandled. The parameter is incorrect."

Comment: There are some issues with what you want to do in case of unhandeled exception. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926155/displaying-error-page-in-wp7-app

Answer (score 0):

```
        try
        {
                   // do something with your crash , report it or write log
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
```

the debug go to the place exception throw .

Comment: I do not want to go to debug. I want the `error.xaml` to be displayed.